# Calculate sum of price on distant relation

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have a booking with a method `total` which calculates the total price of the booking from the sum of all the prices of activities that belong to appointments. A booking has many appointments and the following seems to give the right answer, but it seems horrid.  How can I improve this?

```
  def total 
    # TODO  shouldn't this be a db query?
    total = 0
    self.appointments.each do |appointment|
        unless appointment.activity.price.nil? 
            total += appointment.activity.price.to_f
        end
    end     
    total
  end
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Code Review! I don't know RoR enough to answer, but yes you need to understand how to do a sum query, which will avoid both the loop and the `nil` handling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
def total
  self.appointments.joins(:activity).sum(:price)
end
```

You could perhaps simplify it a little, by making an explicit 2nd order `has_many` on your booking model:

```
has_many :appointments
has_many :activities, :through => :appointments
```

Then you can just do:

```
def total
  self.activities.sum(:price)
end
```

In either case, it'll end up as a single DB-query.

Comment: That has sped things up quite a bit even in my dev environment with a small data set & is obviously much more idomatic / simple / nicer to look at.  Active record continues to amaze.  Thanks.